# How to add local file as background in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Path for my HTML-file: `C:\Users\Name\Documents\Coding\Battleship\index.html`
Path for the picture: `C:\Users\Name\Documents\Coding\Battleship\Water.jpg`

I tried to add it as follows:

```
body {
    background-image: url("file://C:\Users\Name\Documents\Coding\Battleship\Water.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

However, it is not working. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: The file path needs to be relative to the doc root of the webserver your serving it from. Unless you're not using a web server.

Comment: OH that fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the below tested code.

The problem was you were using `background-image` which only accepts one parameter, you were supposed to use `background` which is a shorthand for writing all the background properties into one.

Refer: [CSS background](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) [last section]

You need to change the below CSS

```
body {
        background: url("Water.jpg") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

**Code example:**

```css
html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
}
body {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

**You can't do like this**

```
background-image: url("file://C:\Users\Name\Documents\Coding\Battleship\Water.jpg") no-repeat center center;
```

---

> You can place the image is project root(or subfolder) and use as below

Assume your project folder is `Battleship`

**If you place `Water.jpg` in root(as below)**

```
Battleship
-index.html
-Water.jpg
```

then use this

```
body {
    background-image: url("./Water.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**If you place `Water.jpg` in subfolder (as below)**

```
Battleship
-index.html
-images
    -Water.jpg
```

then use this

```
body {
    background-image: url("./images/Water.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[Check this w3schools.com source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is too late to answer but I think the problem is very simple. You have done the right thing with the URL, here is the tricky bit: the link to your URL has a backward slash(there's no need for using CSS to correct this) ie:
Yours:
Path for my HTML-

```
file: C:\Users\Name\Documents\Coding\Battleship\index.html
```

**Correct Answer**: should have a forward slash
Path for my HTML-file:

```
 C:/Users/Name/Documents/Coding/Battleship/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

just make a folder & put both files into it and link your image path simply.